# meteor templating@1.1.9 compressed file is damaged

Tags: ethereum, wallet

I'm running Ethereum Mist on Windows 7.

and also I wish running the Ethereum wallet.

**[Look at my image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLfn0.png)** 
It has serveral 30 minutes.

But also now it has running.

It looks like templating@1.1.9 compressed file is damaged.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem.

How?

I ran the "`meteor update`".

So that `templating-compiler`, `templating-runtime` is packaged.